# C++ qt inserting duplicate data to sqlite while we have conidtion

Tags: c++, qt

## SQL Data Duplicate Insert

I'm trying to prevent the inserts of duplicate usernames, passwords, phone numbers and email addresses.

**Function added to main file**

```cpp
if(data.open()){
        QString username,password,email,phone;
        username = ui->line_Edit_username_Registery->text();
        password = ui->line_Edit_password_Registery->text();
        email = ui->line_edit_email->text();
        phone = ui->line_edit_phone->text();

        //Query Check
        QSqlQuery queryCheck;
        queryCheck.prepare(QString("SELECT * FROM register where username = :username AND        password = :password AND email = :email AND phone = :phone"));
        queryCheck.bindValue(":username", username);
        queryCheck.bindValue(":password", password);
        queryCheck.bindValue(":email",email);
        queryCheck.bindValue(":phone",phone);


        bool check = true;
        if ( queryCheck.exec())
        {

            while (queryCheck.next()) {
                QString usernameDB,passwordDB,emailDB,phoneDB;
                username_database = queryCheck.value(1).toString();
                password_database = queryCheck.value(2).toString();
                email_database = queryCheck.value(3).toString();
                phone_database = queryCheck.value(4).toString();
                if(username == username_database || phone == phone_database || email == email_database){
                    QMessageBox::information(this,"Error!","Duplicated!");
                    check = false;

                }

            }
        }// End Query Check
```

My problem is preventing the addition of duplicates when inserting data. I wrote this condition:

`if(username == username_database || phone == phone_database || email == email_database)`

So, when I insert a duplicate username, password, phone number and email address, the database sends me message and saying, "Duplicated!". But, when I give it another password, then it is going to insert it in the database.  The condition is to check username, phone number and email address.

**Whole code**

```
void mainwindow::on_pushButton_register_clicked()
{

    if(data.open()){
        QString username,password,email,phone;
        username = ui->line_Edit_username_Registery->text();
        password = ui->line_Edit_password_Registery->text();
        email = ui->line_edit_email->text();
        phone = ui->line_edit_phone->text();

        //Query Check
        QSqlQuery queryCheck;
        queryCheck.prepare(QString("SELECT * FROM register where username = :username AND        password = :password AND email = :email AND phone = :phone"));
        queryCheck.bindValue(":username", username);
        queryCheck.bindValue(":password", password);
        queryCheck.bindValue(":email",email);
        queryCheck.bindValue(":phone",phone);


        bool check = true;
        if ( queryCheck.exec())
        {

            while (queryCheck.next()) {
                QString usernameDB,passwordDB,emailDB,phoneDB;
                username_database = queryCheck.value(1).toString();
                password_database = queryCheck.value(2).toString();
                email_database = queryCheck.value(3).toString();
                phone_database = queryCheck.value(4).toString();
                if(username == username_database || phone == phone_database || email == email_database){
                    QMessageBox::information(this,"Error!","Duplicated!");
                    check = false;

                }

            }
        }// End Query Check


        // query insert
        if(check){
            QSqlQuery query;
            query.prepare("INSERT INTO register (username, password , email , phone) "
                          "VALUES (:username, :password, :email , :phone)");
            query.bindValue(":username", username);
            query.bindValue(":password", password);
            query.bindValue(":email", email);
            query.bindValue(":phone", phone);


                bool chkbox = ui->checkBox->isChecked();
                //Checking checkbox condition
                if (chkbox){
                    if(query.exec())
                        QMessageBox::information(this,"this","yes");
                    else
                        QMessageBox::information(this,"this","no");
                }
                else {
                    QMessageBox::information(this,"title","Please accept the rules");
                }//Checking checkbox condition
        }
    }
    else{
        QMessageBox::information(this,"this","database didn't connect");
    }
}
```

Comment: you probably have a warning when you compile... `while(query.next())` might be always false, and also `if(query.exec())`, so probably adding some `return` after those might be a good starting point

Comment: but code can recognize that there is duplicate user there . the problem is query.exec() returns false in register Button click

Comment: could it be a problem that you open the database a second time in `checkDataBaseRegister()` ? I'm thinking of the 'old connection removed' message

Comment: actually i think this , and i try to import data base to function by adding QSqlDatabase in my function import but i couldn't solve it by that way

Comment: @IngoLeonhardt how can i solve that problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i find the solution . the problem was in selecting table from database and i replace AND by OR and then it checks them one by one .

Answer (score 0):

Consider `checkDataBaseRegister`:
You are executing a query to check if a user exists or not, in case this user exists, you will get a record back, but if it does not exist, then you won't get any record back, and so `while(query.next())` will never be `true`, and your compiler is probably warning you that might happen to reach the end of that function, without any return, so I would suggest you to add some `return` after `while` and `if`:

```
bool MainWindow::checkDataBaseRegister(QString username , QString password , QString email , QString phone){

    QSqlDatabase data = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
    data.setDatabaseName("qt5.sqlite");
    data.open();
    QSqlQuery query;
    query.prepare(QString("SELECT * FROM register where username = :username AND password = :password AND email = :email AND phone = :phone"));
    query.bindValue(":username", username);
    query.bindValue(":password", password);
    query.bindValue(":email",email);
    query.bindValue(":phone",phone);
    if(query.exec())
    {
        while(query.next()){
            QString usernameDB,passwordDB,emailDB,phoneDB;
            usernameDB = query.value(1).toString();
            passwordDB = query.value(2).toString();
            emailDB = query.value(3).toString();
            phoneDB = query.value(4).toString();
            if(username==usernameDB || email == emailDB || phone == phoneDB){
                return false;
            }
            else{
                return true;
            }
        }
        return true;
        // ^^^^^^^^^-- because no records are been returned
    }
    return false;
    // ^^^^^^^^^-- errors on the connection

}
```

Also consider that

```
    while(query.next()){
        QString usernameDB,passwordDB,emailDB,phoneDB;
        usernameDB = query.value(1).toString();
        passwordDB = query.value(2).toString();
        emailDB = query.value(3).toString();
        phoneDB = query.value(4).toString();
        if(username==usernameDB || email == emailDB || phone == phoneDB){
            return false;
        }
        else{
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Might be replaced with a simple

```
return query.size() > 0
```

Comment: should be more than two state.. unable to open database or table (open or query failed), unable to find record and record exists.

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie there are exactly those 3 cases

Comment: it cannot be represented by bool :P program should react on logical error of having problem with database or table :P E.g. create table if it doesn't exist. Or whine to user (or admin)

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie the optimal solution would be to use an exception , but by the looks of thing this is not some super legacy code, so if you only want to check if he can insert a new user (`checkDataBaseRegister`), i think this is enough

Comment: i am so beginner in coding and sorry if this code is so toxic . and i replaced your codes and now what i Register in user it said that it is duplicate but it is not . and can you say where should i replace return query.size() > 0 ?

Comment: QSqlDatabasePrivate::removeDatabase: connection 'qt_sql_default_connection' is still in use, all queries will cease to work.
QSqlDatabasePrivate::addDatabase: duplicate connection name 'qt_sql_default_connection', old connection removed.
QSqlDatabasePrivate::addDatabase: duplicate connection name 'qt_sql_default_connection', old connection removed.
QSqlDatabasePrivate::removeDatabase: connection 'qt_sql_default_connection' is still in use, all queries will cease to work.

Comment: @siamakalipour don't worry about your code ahah `return query.size() > 0` should replace the entire `while` inside the `if`

Comment: @siamakalipour then close the connection before the returns

Comment: @Berto99 i added  return query.size() > 0; entire  while  in  if(username == .... ) and now what i actually import to database . said it is duplicate . but it is not

Comment: @siamakalipour your code should look like: `if(query.exec()) return query.size() > 0; else return false`

Comment: @Berto99 you mean that i should remove whole while(query.next() ) ? so where should it check the table from database that it is exist there . i did that and remove whole while query.next but there is problem that all of the user imports are duplicate

Comment: @Berto99 can it be the problem from opening database twice ! and cant exec query next time in main fucntion of button ? and  IngoLeonhardt points to it